# Detect a video upload YouTube API

Tags: c#, youtube-data-api

I'm developing a bot for discord and I would like to ask you how could I detect when I upload a video to Youtube to send a message to all users on my discord's server. I know some servers who use this function. Thank you!

Comment: Have you had a look at the YouTube API? Is there some sort of webhook?

Answer (score 2):

You can use subscribe to YouTube's Data API push notification via [PubSubHubbub](https://github.com/pubsubhubbub/).

The approach can be summarised as:

1. Set up a callback server that can handle incoming Atom feed notifications.
2. Use the Google hub to subscribe to receive push notifications.
3. Process notifications sent to your callback server.

Detailed instructions can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications).

It is worth noting that the PubSubHubbub sample I read was using Node.